# how to change the navigation back item function ,back to rootView

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I have a problem.

I use `show(vc)` to present a view controller.

vc1 --> vc2 --> vc3

I want to redirect user from vc1 when user clicks on back button on vc3, to achieve that I am using the below mentioned code.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "<", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(backToRoot(sender:)))
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton 
}

func backToRoot(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    _ = self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```

I want the default image of back button, not customized button.

Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: Thank Parth Bhatt edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made this today. I found no way to change action of system back button. In order to look like the system style, I draw a same picture(snapshot the simulator, and change in photo shop). The code is as followed:

```
let button: UIButton = UIButton(type: .system)
```

the default size of height is 30, width is whatever you set

```
button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 30)
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "BackButton"), for: .normal)
```

the default font is the following:

```
button.setTitle("Back", for: .normal)
button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext", size: 15)
```

This is the trick, you need find out the same position with the system's, the following is my result, I had adjusted many times. I hope you could use, but I think you need find your own size

```
button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -43, 0, 0)
button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -33, 0, 0)

button.addTarget(target, action: action, for: .touchUpInside)
let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
```